# In SQL How to Get a sum of data from a whole year

Tags: sql

My code looks like this

```
SELECT FORMAT (sum (DISTINCT(b.Amount_Total)),'c' ) 
FROM Customer a
INNER JOIN
OrderHead b ON a.Customer_Id = b.Customer_Id
INNER JOIN
Order_ c ON b.Order_Id = c.Order_Id
WHERE Name = 'John Smith' AND b.Order_date between '2013/01/01' and '2013/12/31'
```

But I don't know if I'm getting the right sum for what John spent in 2013

Comment: What makes you think the answer is wrong?

Comment: you probably aren't. DISTINCT will cause a problem, and maybe your date range.

Answer (score 1):

Take off the DISTINCT. If he has 2 orders for 100.00 each isn't that $200.00?

```
SELECT FORMAT (sum(b.Amount_Total),'c' ) 
FROM Customer a
INNER JOIN
OrderHead b ON a.Customer_Id = b.Customer_Id
INNER JOIN
Order_ c ON b.Order_Id = c.Order_Id
WHERE Name = 'John Smith' AND b.Order_date between '2013/01/01' and '2013/12/31'
```

if b.Order_date is a datetime and includes the time, you would use '2013/12/31 23:59:59'